# Modifying Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in IIS

Tags: .net, http, iis-7, http-headers, access-control

Does anyone know how or where IIS sets this header?
For some reason all responses returned from my site contain "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * " and I'm interested in removing or modifying the value of this header.
Where and when IIS sets it? (its not something in my code).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from Microsoft [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733102(v=ws.10).aspx)

> 1. Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage. For information about opening IIS Manager, see Open IIS Manager (IIS 7). For information about navigating to locations in the UI, see Navigation in IIS Manager (IIS 7).
> 2. In Features View, double-click HTTP Response Headers.
> 3. On the HTTP Response Headers page, select the header that you want to remove.
> 4. In the Actions pane, click Remove and then click Yes.

Comment: This header that I want to remove ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin") does't appear there...

Comment: Can you provide us with more details about your environment. .net version, any frameworks or libraries you are using, your hosting setting, etc. If it is not in IIS Manager and your code it might be generated anywhere else in your page life-cycle.

Comment: thanks Rafie but the problem is solved. it turns out that the application is adding the header, i didn't search it right :-)